# Привязка из шаблона DataGridCell к коллекции внутри DataGridColumn в рамках элемента DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Попробовал реализовать свою задумку самостоятельно, но упёрся в тупик. Вот, что имею в проекте.

Использую DataGrid для отображения данных. Он в свою очередь находится внутри кастомного UserControl, в который также с помощью привязок поставляются поставляются коллекции данных типа ObservableCollection<string>.

**Table.xaml**

```xaml
<UserControl>
     <!--...-->
     <DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectionUnit="Cell">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
             <dgc:DataGridTextColumnWithCollection ColumnDataCollection="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Collection1}"/>
             <dgc:DataGridTextColumnWithCollection ColumnDataCollection="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Collection2}"/>
             ...
         </DataGrid.Columns>
     </DataGrid>
     <!--...-->
</UserControl>
```

**Table.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Table : UserControl
{
    //...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Collection1Property = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Collection1",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<string>),
        typeof(Table),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, null, null));

    public ObservableCollection<string> Collection1
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(Collection1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Collection1Property, value); }
    }
    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Collection2Property = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Collection2",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<string>),
        typeof(Table),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, null, null));

    public ObservableCollection<string> Collection2
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(Collection2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Collection2Property, value); }
    }
    //...
}
```

В качестве колонок используется самописный наследник от DataGridTextColumn, которому добавлено свойство с коллекцией:

**DataGridTextColumnWithCollection.cs**

```
public class DataGridTextColumnWithCollection : DataGridTextColumn
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnDataCollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ColumnDataCollection",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<string>),
            typeof(DataGridTextColumnWithCollection),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, null, null));

        public ObservableCollection<string> ColumnDataCollection
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ColumnDataCollectionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ColumnDataCollectionProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

И, наконец, в шаблоне DataGridCell к нему приписан Popup с ListBox, который является конечной точкой в цепи привязок

**CustomDataGrid.xaml**

```xaml
<ResourceDictionary>
    <!--...-->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Border>
        <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            <Popup Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                <Grid x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}, Path=Column.ColumnDataCollection}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!--...-->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Суть моей задачи** - добиться того, чтобы в Popup-элементе у каждой DataGridCell отображался набор элементов, в зависимости от того, в каком столбце находится клетка. Эти элементы никак не зависят от Item-ов самого DataGrid-а и не являются ими или их частью.

Вышеописанная попытка с цепью привязок и кастомным свойством зависимости у столбца не сработала. Точно не понимаю, в каком месте происходит сбой, однако сильнее всего меня смущает эта привязка (CustomDataGrid.xaml):

```xaml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}, Path=Column.ColumnDataCollection}"/>
```

Поэтому, буду рад как определению ошибок в моём решении, так и предложенным альтернативам решению задачи с коллекциями у клеток в зависимости от колонок.

**upd 1.** Вот источник данных, к которым привяжутся свойства UserControl-a:

```
public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    // ...
    public ViewModel ()
    {
        Source1 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Source2 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Source1.Add("стол");
        Source1.Add("шкаф");
        Source2.Add("белый");
        Source2.Add("красный");
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Source1 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Source2 { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

И примерно такого результата хочу добиться:

[image: Popup клетки с коллекцией строк]

Comment: А вы без попапа и юзерконтрола для начала смогли этого добиться? Или я не понял, что такое попап.

Comment: @aepot, popup - всплывающее окно. Хочу в нём разместить коллекцию строк в зависимости от колонки, в которой находится клетка. Пробовал вывести в этот Popup свойство FontSize, которым обладает DataGridTextColumn - выводится. И в user control данные по привязкам успешно доходят. А вот на моменте с кастомной колонкой - тупик. То ли в свойство зависимости этой колонки данные не подвязываются, то ли ListBox не может эти данные получить...

Comment: Пока непонятно, приведите конкретный пример исходных данных, и что именно хотите увидеть в интерфейсе.

Comment: @aepot, вопрос дополнен.

Comment: Удалось разобраться? Если ответ был полезен, пожалуйста отметьте его принятым.

Comment: @aepot, в процессе экспериментов. Направление в сторону стандартных DataGridComboBoxColumn, скорее всего, верно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам просто надо изменить структуру данных.

```cs
public class DataItem
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Source1 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Source2 { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> Items { get; set; }

    public ViewModel ()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
        DataItem data = new DataItem
        {
            Source1 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            Source2 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        };
        Items.Add(data);
        data.Source1.Add("стол");
        data.Source1.Add("шкаф");
        data.Source2.Add("белый");
        data.Source2.Add("красный");
    }
}
```

И немного привести в порядок привязки.

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectionUnit="Cell">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <dgc:DataGridTextColumnWithCollection ColumnDataCollection="{Binding Source1}"/>
        <dgc:DataGridTextColumnWithCollection ColumnDataCollection="{Binding Source2}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```xml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Border>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Presenter" />
            <Popup Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                <Grid x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="{Binding Text, ElementName=Presenter}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Правда я не понял, по какому условию здесь выскакивает `Popup`, и мысль в том, что придется из код-бихайнда открывать попап по событию клика на текстблок.

Кстати попробуйте [стандартную колонку](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.8) `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, она наверное делает практически то что вам нужно, только примените свои стили к комбобоксу, или даже вкрутите свой темплейт в него, и не придется мучать саму табличку. Используйте свойство `DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle` чтобы задать стиль комбобокса.