# Из таблицы выводит только первый элемент

Tags: c#, wpf

Класс PageStudents тут вывожу имена студентов

```
 public partial class PageStudents : Page
    {
        public static TitleStudentEntities DataEntitlesStudents { get; set; }
        ObservableCollection<Student> ListStudents;
      
        private bool isDirty = true;
        public PageStudents()
        {
            DataEntitlesStudents = new TitleStudentEntities();
            InitializeComponent();
            ListStudents = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        }
        private void Page_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var students = DataEntitlesStudents.Students;
            var queryStudents = from Student in students
                                orderby Student.name
                                select Student;
            foreach (Student emp in queryStudents)
            {
                ListStudents.Add(emp);

            }
            DataGridStudents.ItemsSource = ListStudents;
        }
        

    }
}
```

Класс ListGroup этим пытаюсь вывести название группы но выводит только самое первое значение

```
class ListGroup : ObservableCollection<Group>
    {
        public ListGroup()
        {
            DbSet<Group> groups = PageStudents.DataEntitlesStudents.Groups;
            var queryGroup = from Group in groups select Group;
            foreach (Group group1 in queryGroup)
            {
                this.Add(group1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Привязка столбца dataGrid  при наведении на Binding groupName пишет элемент не найден в контексте ListGroup

```
 <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Группа" Binding="{Binding groupName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource listGroup }}"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: `public static TitleStudentEntities` - плохо, это сразу говорит о том, что у вас проблема в построении архитектуры проекта. `Page` - тоже [не лучший выбор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228886/220553) в WPF. `from Student in students` -> `var queryStudents = students.OrderBy(x=>x.Name);`. `DataGridStudents.ItemsSource` - это должно быть задано лишь раз, как `DataContext` окна. `Весь код в PageStudents` - его лучше вынести в отдельный клсс, не смешивайте UI и логику, сильно пожалеете потом. `ObservableCollection<Group>` - зачем? `Source={StaticResource listGroup }` - зачем?

Comment: Source={StaticResource listGroup } это сслыка на класс

Comment: И зачем она там? Вы "ссылку на класс" сделали здесь `DataGridStudents.ItemsSource = ListStudents;`, то есть ваш `DataGrid` взял `ListStudents` как источник данных, далее вам надо привязывать колонки к свойствам, которые находятся внутри `ListStudents`, например `{Binding Name}`, а для чего-то в привязке понаписали кучу лишнего. Исправляйте все недочеты, о которых я вам сказал и будет работать.

Comment: В общем и целом привязка к коллкции делается [как-то так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/797321/373567) или [даже так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266956/373567).